# Do gnostic valentinians contribute their sect nowadays?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion, christianity, history

Why did people abandon Valentinian teachings and why isn't it practiced today?

Here are links to who Valentinus was, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentinus_(Gnostic), and a summary of his views:  http://gnosis.org/library/valentinus/Brief_Summary_Theology.htm

Comment: @Dcleve I doubt your answer would be very welcome on Christianity.se

Comment: @JamesK -- moral critiques of a religion from outside its orthodoxy are often unwelcome.  I have only just joined ChrSE, so if this question is asked there, I will offer my answer.

Comment: @Dcleve I think this is a more appropriate site than Christianity for this. It is also more authentic and more useful than most theology questions that get thrown around.

Comment: And Ive upvoted both the question and your (v good) answer. As @JamesK correctly points out this would not work on the Christianity site and in general questions that rock the foundations would typically not fly on any religion site.

Comment: @Rushi -- as this question appears unlikely to remain open on Christianity SE, so it cannot be migrated there, I have withdrawn my close vote.

Comment: To the questioner I'd say: You can reduce the close votes by ading some more detail

Answer (score 1):

In the first century, Christians did not have a theological dogma, and there was significant diversity in what "Christian" meant.

During the 2nd century, the inclination to dogmatize the religion caught on, and many of the diverse theological branches of Christianity were expelled by the orthodox dogmatists.

By the third century, dogmatism rose to the full flower it would maintain in the religion for a millennia and a half, and Gnostics, including all followers of Valentinus, were murdered, and their writings burned.

It is possible to exterminate a viewpoint by exterminating those who hold it, and their writings.

This was also the fate of much of the writings and followers of other non-orthodox versions of Christianity besides Gnosticism, and of other rival religions.  This includes much of Greek philosophy.  The Rennaissance is generally attributed to the contact with the Greek philosophy that was NOT mostly burned in the Muslim world.

The splintering of Christianity today into multiple sects, and the revival of Paganism, Wicca, and the development of New Age and other non-Christian religions in the West is only because this murderous dogmatism was defeated in the wars of religion in the 1600s.

One of the Gnostic monks was able to preserve a small portion of the Gnostic writings in a well in Egypt before he was murdered by the orthodox. Those writings were only discovered in 1945, and are called the Nag Hamadi library. This is our primary source material for Gnosticism today.

Note, from a Gnostic POV, murderous dogmatism was the successful building up, then capture of the church Hierarchy by the Antagonist.

Comment: When ppl rant and rail at Christianity they typically have a few pet peeves — crusades, inquisition, witch-hunts [Most important of course is a certain US president!] These 3rd century events [Im assuming youre referring to the Nicene council?] dont get mentioned though in the sense of impact on human civilization they're probably more harmful

Comment: @Rishi -- the installation of Orthodoxy included the destruction of the Hellenistic temples and murder of the Oracles and philosophers, destruction of the Mithraic temples and presumably murder of its priests, likewise with Manicheans.  The murder of Nestorians and Arians too was a splintering within the dogmatic orthodox movement.  This murderous orthodoxy was perpetuated up thru the early stages of the protestant reformation, and was only stopped by the number and military competence of the protestants.

Comment: @Rushi And yes, the 3rd century period where Christian theologians captured control of the governance of Europe and much of the middle east, and ended freedom of thought thru murder of all rival viewpoints, was a truly horrific time for the history of freedom of thought in the world.  The extermination of pagan religions of N Europe, and of Cathars, Bogomils, Native American religions, and Moravians, were part of a long continuation of this horror.